# Problem with submenus

Tags: bash, menu

I'm trying to write a script with two menus, one with basic commands, and the other password protected with five more advanced commands; but the script doesn't pass the first menu. I think that there is a loop but I can't find it.

```
    #!/bin/bash 
    #Muestra el menu general
    function _menuPrincipal()
    {
echo "1) Opciones basicas"
echo "2) Opciones avanzadas"
echo "3) Salir"
echo
echo -n "Indica una opcion: "
  }

 function _submenu1()
{
echo
echo "1) Directorio actual"
echo "2) Listar archivos"
echo "3) Quien soy"
echo "4) fecha"
echo "5) Permisos creacion"
echo "6) Info OpenGL"
echo "7) Tiempo funcionamiento"
echo "8) Calendario mes"
echo "9) Calendario 2016"
echo "10) Reloj BIOS"
echo "11) Nombre de la maquina"
echo "12) Historial de comandos"
echo "13) Estado actual de la terminal"
echo "14) Sistema actual"
echo "15) Nombre terminal"
echo "16) Salir"
echo
echo -n "Indica una opcion: "
}

 function _submenu2()
{
echo
echo "1) Dispositivos"
echo "2) Procesos"
echo "3) Particiones"
echo "4) Archivos abiertos"
echo "5) Test memoria"
echo "6) Salir"
echo
echo -n "Indica una opcion: "
 }

 opc=0
 until [ "$opc" -eq "16" ]
do
    case $opc in
    1)
        opc1=0
        until [ $opc1 -eq 16 ]
        do
            case $opc1 in
                1)
                    pwd
                    ;;
                2)
                    ls
                    ;;
                3)
                    whoami
                    ;;
                4)
                    date
                    ;;
                5)
                    umask
                    ;;
                6)
                    glxinfo
                    ;;
                7)
                    uptime
                    ;;
                8)
                    cal
                    ;;
                9)
                    cal -my
                    ;;
                10)
                    hwclock --show
                    ;;
                11)
                    hostname
                    ;;
                12)
                    history
                    ;;
                13)
                    mesg
                    ;;
                14)
                    uname
                    ;;
                15)
                    tty
                    ;;
                *)
                    _submenu1
                    ;;
            esac
            read opc1
        done
        _menuPrincipal
        ;;
    2)
        opc2=0
        until [ $opc2 -eq 6 ]
        do
            case $opc2 in
                1)
                    df -vh
                    ;;
                2)
                    top
                    ;;
                3)
                    cfdisk
                    ;;
                4)
                    lsof
                    ;;
                5)
                    memtest
                    ;;
                *)
                    _submenu2
                    ;;
            esac
            read opc2
        done
        _menuPrincipal
        ;;
    *)
        _menuPrincipal
        ;;
esac
read opc
done
```

Comment: You outer loop should exit if `opc` is 3, not 16.

Comment: You might want to look into `select` rather than the structure you have here; that's the purpose for which it was designed.

Comment: I tried fixing the external loop with 3 but it keeps showing "[: too many arguments" on that line